# VZ Buyers Incomplete Issue

Tags: expresso-store, vz-buyers

We have an issue where an incomplete transaction is showing up on VZ Buyers like the person bought the items.  However the transaction was incomplete and the transaction failed so it was not taken out of stock but it's still listed.  Does anyone have a fix for this?

Our system has to be very precise with us selling 100 items at a time can't have room for buyer error by any means.  Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: VZ Buyer module is probably the problem as I expect it hooks into Expresso store on new orders and doesn't update if the order changes (e.g. payment doesn't go through). I'd suggest you contact the developer (http://devot-ee.com/developers/eli-van-zoeren) or post of the support forum via Devot-ee: http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/support/vz-buyers/viewforum/1921

Comment: Sucks.  No one has replied to us at all.

Comment: Did you try contacting VZ Buyers developers? Failing any response from them you'll need to look at modifying the add-on to see what Store hook it's using - it should be using store_order_complete_end. Failing that you'll have to add an additional hook that fires and checks when the order status is changed, to ensure the order has gone through - this would use the store_orders_datatable hook.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like a bug in VZ Buyers. Are you talking about the fieldtype displayed in the CP, or the `{exp:vz_buyers:print_csv}` tag?

A quick glance at the [source code](https://github.com/elivz/vz_buyers.ee_addon/blob/master/vz_buyers/mod.vz_buyers.php) looks like it is not restricting the list to only completed orders.

If you open up that file, right around line 48 you will see this:

```
->join('store_orders', 'store_orders.order_id = store_order_items.order_id')
```

After that, add this line:

```
->where('store_orders.order_completed_date >', 0)
```

You might need to make a similar adjustment to the fieldtype file (ft.vz_buyers.php). Without this change then it will treat incomplete orders (which are still carts) as if they were real orders.